# What means `crop` in FFT calculation?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, dft, fast-convolution, overlap-add

In [soapy power manual](https://github.com/xmikos/soapy_power):

> Crop:   -o PERCENT, --overlap PERCENT
> percent of overlap when frequency hopping (incompatible with -k)
> -k PERCENT, --crop PERCENT
> percent of crop when frequency hopping (incompatible with -o)

I know the `overlap`,what means `crop` in FFT calculation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"to crop" means "to cut off at the end".

In the case of this program (which is a bit obscure), it is just used in one place, `psd.result`'s [source code](https://github.com/xmikos/soapy_power/blob/v1.6.1/soapypower/psd.py#L51-L54):

```
    if self._crop_factor:
        crop_bins_half = round((self._crop_factor * self._bins) / 2)
        freq_array = freq_array[crop_bins_half:-crop_bins_half]
        pwr_array = pwr_array[crop_bins_half:-crop_bins_half]
```

So, instead of the full calculated PSD you just get a "cropped" version, centered around the middle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.What's the scenario to use `crop` instead of `overlap`?

Comment: Can't tell you. I'd never use it.